Is every second-countable weakly locally compact space also locally compact?
A second countable space has a countable basis. A weakly locally compact space has a compact neighborhood for each point of the space; in particular, every compact space is weakly locally compact. A locally compact space has a local basis of compact neighborhoods for each point of the space; the one-point compactification of the rationals is a standard example that not all compact spaces are locally compact.
The one-point compactification of the rationals is not second-countable. Does there exist a second-countable example? This would answer a currently open search on π-Base: https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=Second+countable%2BWeakly+locally+compact%2B%7ELocally+compact

The theorem is not true. S185 of π-Base is compact and second-countable, but not locally compact.
S185: Consider
the set $\omega^2\cup\{\infty_x,\infty_y\}$ with points of
$\omega^2$ isolated, neighborhoods of $\infty_x$ containing
all but finitely-many columns, and neighborhoods of $\infty_y$
containing all by finitely-many rows.
Consider a neighborhood $U$ of $\infty_x$ missing $\infty_y$, and any neighborhood $V\subseteq U$ of $\infty_x$. Then $V$ contains a column of $\omega^2$, which is closed and discrete in $V$, showing $V$ is not compact.

We can compactify a topological space $(X,\tau)$ by adding a top element $\top \notin X$ and using $\tau \cup \{X \cup \{\top\}\}$ as the new topology. Since we are only adding a single open set, this preserves being countably-based. As $X$ is an open subspace of this compactification, the compactification of $X$ cannot be locally compact if $X$ is not. (The resulting space is not $T_1$ unless $X$ was empty, which is probably a reason for this construction to not be more popular.)
By applying this construction to any countably-based space non-locally compact space, we obtain a space which is countably-based, weakly locally compact but not locally compact.

This construction is sometimes called the non-Hausdorff cone. It shares some important topological properties with the regular cone.

It's a good construction for counter-examples nonetheless, thanks. The space I found happens to be semi-Hausdorff; I wonder if there's a construction to obtain a semi-Hausdroff (or at least T_1) example in general.
